# Oracle: fullscan instead of composite index using

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have strange oracle optimizer behaviour:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.date_insert,
       a.message#cnt
  FROM T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT A,
       T_LIST l 
 WHERE a.priority_id = 0 
   AND a.status = 'Q'
   and l.id = a.list_id
```

This query produces fullscan over `T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT`, regardless the fact that it is an index covered `priority_id` and `status` fields:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX INFORMER.IX$MESSAGE_TRANSMIT$6 ON INFORMER.T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT (STATUS, PRIORITY_ID)
```

The table size is about 28M rows and it has been analyzed 7 days ago (since that day just several thousands rows were added).

If I use a hint `/*+index(a IX$MESSAGE_TRANSMIT$6) */` then everything becomes good, as well as if I remove join, and rewrite query to:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.date_insert,
       a.message#cnt
  FROM T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT A,
 WHERE a.priority_id = 0 
   AND a.status = 'Q'
```

Where could I make mistake?

**UPD**:

The issue was in this optimizer setting:

```
optimizer_mode  first_rows_10
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: statistics were updated 7 days ago.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I thinkg **UPD** can be interesting for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What proportion of the rows match the priority id/status criteria ?

If, for example, 20% of the rows match then it will have to visit the row in 20% of cases to obtain the extra details. If it is visiting 20% of the rows, it will probably visit 80-90% of the blocks. In which case it would be correct to ignore the index.

However, if it is using the index for the query without the join, then it is more likely due to the a.list_id value. If it uses the BITMAP index, for every row it finds there, it has to access the T_LIST table by id. If T_LIST is large and id is not indexed then this might mean repeated full scans of T_LIST are a bad idea.

In which case it might get all the matching rows from T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT, sort them by ID and then get the matching rows from T_LIST. A hash join to T_LIST may also be appropriate.

Also, are you sure you don't simple want to do a

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.date_insert,
       a.message#cnt
  FROM T_MESSAGE_TRANSMIT A
 WHERE a.priority_id = 0 
   AND a.status = 'Q'
   AND a.list_id in (select l.id from T_LIST l)
```

If an id isn't unique on T_LIST, your original SQL would generate duplicates.

Comment: Not much: ~1k. Yes `list_id` isn't in index. And yes, this query could be rewritten also with nested select in `SELECT` or `WHERE` part. I'm just curious why doesn't oracle use the index (as I mentioned, the query with the hint works incredible fast).

Comment: "If it uses the BITMAP index, for every row it finds there, it has to access the T_LIST table by id." --- oracle should do it anyway: fields in select are not covered with index either.

Comment: "Also, are you sure you don't simple want to do a" --- may be. It is a simplification of one really huge query with a lot of nested queries.

Comment: Gary's answer is mostly right - certainly I don't see any reason for using a bitmap index here. How do the number of GETs compare using the hinted and unhinted query?

Comment: Even though this answer is not right (it is correct as a theory, but not applicable in my case) - I check it because I don't like to left questions unanswered. And for audience information: the issue was in `optimizer_mode first_rows_10` setting. Thanks Gary, and +1 to you :-)